# Increasing the size of plot in grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I would like to plot a bar chart and a table below it using ggplot2 and knitting to word via Rmd. However, I need my plot to be a bit bigger and my respective table to be a bit smaller. The current code produces a very small bar plot. Below is a working example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

#plot

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g<-g + geom_bar()

#table
dat<-mpg %>% count(class) %>% 
  t() %>%   
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)


table <- tableGrob(dat)

#table and plot

plot2_fin<-grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(), g ,
                    widths=c(3,8)), 
arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(nullGrob(),table, widths=c(3,18,1)),
                                    heights=c(1,1)))

plot2_fin
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider moving from grid to cowplot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

#plot

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g<-g + geom_bar()

#table
dat<-mpg %>% count(class) %>% 
  t() %>%   
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)


table <- tableGrob(dat)

#table and plot

library(cowplot)


plot_grid(g, table, 
          ncol = 1, 
          rel_heights = c(4, 1))
```

[image: example from cowplot]